# Monitor ConfigAndLog .log file in real time

Tags: drupal, upgrade, configuration, logs

I am upgrading the CiviCRM and would like to monitor the current .log file that is in `<drupal root>/sites/default/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/` as it's being updated, in real time. Currently, I know how to view it using the `cat` command via command line on demand only. Is there a command that prints the latest entry as they happen?

I know this probably is less of CiviCRM question and more of a linux question, but others debugging and monitoring CiviCRM processes might find it helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tail -f /your/log/file` will show you lines as they are added to the file.