# Where is the exact path to the ConfigAndLog log *file*?

Tags: php, logs, debugging

In the [latest awesome pattern](https://civicrm.org/blog/totten/the-static-is-dead-long-live-the-static) we can now locate our log service easily:

```
Civi::log()->info('Hello, log!');
```

And then we can [tail the log](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16365/monitor-configandlog-log-file-in-real-time) which is in our `ConfigAndLog` directory. Chris has enumerated [the other log files around](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6399/how-do-i-debug-civicrm-when-i-hit-a-blank-page-white-screen-fatal-error) and Jon has described [where to find the directory in different CMS's](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15931/where-are-the-configandlog-and-templates-c-directories) but I need to have a one liner to point me directly at the current log file.

For me, right this second, it is:

`/opt/buildkit/build/dmaster/sites/default/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/CiviCRM.e6449e3815b7721f267195e2.log`

How do I find this next time without having to go hunting around? Ideally I'm after a `cv` based one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

Found it!

The log file is named by `CRM_Exception::generateLogFileName($prefix);`  in `civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php`.

Comment: I tried to make this into a `cv` command and failed. I got as far as `
cv ev "CRM_Exception::createDebugLogger(); return \Civi::$statics['CRM_Core_Error']['logger_file'];"` but alas it just returned false :-/

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment,

```
cv ev 'CRM_Core_Error::createDebugLogger(); return \Civi::$statics['CRM_Core_Error']['logger_file'];'
```

- Might run into trouble with bash treating the square brackets as wildcards when using double quotes as above?
- `CRM_Core_Error` not `CRM_Exception` worked for me.

Not sure what you're using this for, but an easier path might be to use wildcards. When developing I tend to just

```
tail -f sites/*/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/*log
```

and similar when collecting logfiles to some central service.